# Is there any intuitive way to simplify $\frac {\sin x} {\cos 3x} +\frac{\sin 3x}{\cos 9x} +\frac{\sin 9x}{\cos 27 x}$?

Tags: trigonometry

The expression I was trying to simplify was this :

$$\frac {\sin x} {\cos 3x}+ \frac{\sin 3x}{\cos 9x} +\frac{\sin 9x}{\cos 27 x}$$

This question does have answers here
[Show that $\frac{\sin x}{\cos 3x}+\frac{\sin 3x}{\cos 9x}+\frac{\sin 9x}{\cos 27x} = \frac{1}{2}\left(\tan 27x-\tan x\right)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/344505/show-that-frac-sin-x-cos-3x-frac-sin-3x-cos-9x-frac-sin-9x-cos-27)

And also here and here : https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1299968

[Concept of Trigonometric identities](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1854289)

However, all of the answers in these questions are the same method; the method that I have given below.

I was working with this expression for a long time, and finally, I looked it up online.

The only way I saw online to simplify this is by:-
$$\frac {\sin x} {\cos 3x}=\frac {\sin x} {\cos 3x} * \frac {\cos x} {\cos x}$$
$$= \frac {\sin x  \cos x} {\cos 3x\cos x}$$
$$= \frac{\sin 2x}{2*\cos 3x  \cos x}$$
$$=\frac 1 2 *\frac {\sin 2x} {\cos 3x  \cos x}$$
$$=\frac 1 2 *\frac{\sin (3x-x)}{\cos 3x  \cos x}$$
$$=\frac 1 2 * \frac {\sin 3x\cos x -\cos 3x\sin x} {\cos 3x\cos x}$$
$$= \frac 1 2 * (\tan 3x - \tan x)$$

So you first have to know to multiply this expression with $\frac {\cos x} {\cos x}$, then you have to realise that $\sin x\cos x = \frac {\sin 2x} 2$. and then you have to realise that $\sin 2x= \sin (3x-x)$.

This is very unintuitive. The first thing anyone not familiar with this would try to do is to convert $\cos 3x$ in terms of $\cos x$, and then work from there.

So this is my question. Is there any intuitive way to work out this expression?

Comment: $\frac {\sin x} {\cos 3x}$ is an expression, not an equation. It what sense do you want to “solve” it?

Comment: What does "solve" mean? What were you trying to do? Why is the final expression better than the one you started out with?

Comment: Edited with more info

Comment: So you are referring to this question [Show that $\frac{\sin x}{\cos 3x}+\frac{\sin 3x}{\cos 9x}+\frac{\sin 9x}{\cos 27x} = \frac{1}{2}\left(\tan 27x-\tan x\right)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/344505/show-that-frac-sin-x-cos-3x-frac-sin-3x-cos-9x-frac-sin-9x-cos-27) ? Also answered at https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1299968 and https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1854289.

Comment: Yes, but In all of these questions, the same non-intuitive method is used.

Comment: The telescoping part is the intuitive part.